# combine multiple text files into one single tsv file

Tags: r, database, data-analysis

I have 254 text files in total. I want to convert all the text file into one single tsv file in r-programming. How can I do it? Even if it's not possible in r, is there any other way I can do it?

```
 path <- setwd("~/syeda_demo/transcripts/")

 files <- list.files(path = 'path', 
                pattern = '\\.txt$', full.names = TRUE)

map_dfr(files, read_table) %>%
      write_tsv('path/newfile.tsv')`
```

Comment: If you are setting the working directoy, you don't need the `path`.  Also, the `path = path` and not `'path'`.   In your case, it is `files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.txt$', full.names = TRUE)` as it is your working directory.  Even can skip the `full.names =TRUE`.  In the `write_tsv('newfile.tsv')`.  I mentioned `/path/to/your/folder` meaning your actual path and not the literal `/path/to/your/folder`

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Do you get any error?

Answer (score 1):

We get the list of files from the folder with `list.files`, then loop over the files, use `read_table` from `readr` to read all of them, row bind them into a single data set (`_dfr`) and write it back as new file with `write_tsv`

```
library(readr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
files <- list.files(path = '/path/to/your/folder', 
            pattern = '\\.txt$', full.names = TRUE)
map_dfr(files, read_table) %>%
      write_tsv(path = '/path/to/your/folder/yourfile.tsv')
```

---

If the files are really big, we could use `fread/fwrite` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
fwrite(rbindlist(lapply(files, fread), fill = TRUE), 
    file = "/path/to/your/folder/yourfile.tsv", sep="\t")
```

Comment: Do I need to create a new file(yourfile.tsv) before running the map_dfr code? Actually I didn't do that and it gives me error                  
"Error in open.connection(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection"

Comment: @ash1 may be specify `path = `

Comment: I attached the code, but it still gives error.

Answer (score 1):

It is much more memory efficient to do this in a shell system command. For example on Mac OS or Linux enter the following in the Terminal:

```
cat ~/syeda_demo/transcripts/*.txt > ~/syeda_demo/transcripts/path/newfile.tsv
```

This will print all text files into a single file so that every line in each file will be a new row in your tsv.

You can run this within an R session with the "system" command:

```
> system("cat ~/syeda_demo/transcripts/*.txt > ~/syeda_demo/transcripts/path/newfile.tsv")
```

To read such a large file into R I recommend `data.table::fread` or `vroom::vroom`.